# What's the rule of the sha1 code directory in gradle cache path?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to download jar from network, and add it into the gradle cache(.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1), but I don't know how to generate the SHA1 directory of it.

And I learned from network, knew the SHA1 code was generated by jar's URL(i.e. http://4thline.org/m2/org/fourthline/cling/cling-core/2.1.1/cling-core-2.1.1.jar), and the SHA1 directory is the SHA1 code of the URL, but it's not right when I verified it.
So I want to figure it out what the rule is.

For example, the SHA1 code of this URL (http://4thline.org/m2/org/fourthline/cling/cling-core/2.1.1/cling-core-2.1.1.jar) is `c68bd953b6f2b0b7022a3ca26afeb6ecd40dbeef`, but the SHA1 code generated by Gradle is `767954a4d738b8c77606d19a6c0255193651ccba`
they are not same.

Check these pictures

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

At last, Hope you guys can provide some useful info please.
Thank you!

Comment: The Gradle dependency cache is more than just an artifact repository. Adding dependencies manually is discouraged if not practically impossible. Why would do that in the first place? Gradle can resolve dependencies from various locations. It's super flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the `SHA` of file with `SHA` of url. The sha you are considering from `gradle` is the sha of url from where the jar is downloaded. `gradle` maintains sha of url for caching and avoid multiple downloads of jar in the `dependency tree`. As you know, sha will be unique so existing dependency jar will never download again until you change the dependency itself. Wheres the file sha is a kind of signature to ensure the content of file is not modified and it's as-is. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to do that, while it will work, *if done right*, for the `file` cache, it will not work for the metadata cache.

And because Gradle strives for reproducible build, you will only save the *download* of the file, not the fact that the Gradle build needs to define a repository where the file can be found and where a `HEAD` request will confirm its `SHA1`.